# Is controller deprecated in ember 2.0?

Tags: ember.js

The official Ember.js 2.0 release [post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/08/13/ember-2-0-released.html) reads

> the use-cases for Controllers have largely been eliminated in Ember 2.0

Is controller been deprecated like views?

Answer (score 2):

No not all controllers have been deprecated as of ember 2.0. The transition to routable components will land somewhere in 2.x so you can still use Ember.Controller. The controllers that have been deprecated though are ObjectController and ArrayController.